# Var members in a class

Tags: c++, templates

I'll try and explain it more clearly with a example. I have a Square and I want to be able to initialise it with variable dimensions such as

(width,length) = (int, int) or (double, int) or (double, double) etc..

I know that if I wanted my square to have integer sides I would just declare it as `int width` and `int height` but how do I declare it so it can take many forms ?

eg:

**header.h**

```
    class Square 
    {
        public:
            // Constructor : Initialise dimensions
            Square();

            // Set dimensions
            template< typename T1, typename T2>
            setDim(T1 x, T2 y);

        private:
            // Is this right ????
            template <typename T> T width;
            template <typename T> T height;
    };
```

Moreover, if I do create the square how would I initialise the variables to be 0.

e.g:

**src.cpp**

```
Square::Square()
{
    // Would this be correct ???
    width = 0;
    height = 0;
}
```

Comment: Templates are often header-only declaration + definition.

Comment: You can't use a template for just the constructor and variable like that - this would make the type of `width` and `height` unknown until runtime. Instead, you'd have to store a type that can be one of any of the possible types. However, that seems ridiculous for something like this. You could template the class and provide conversions between other instantiations if there's a conversion between their respective types. I'm not sure what your requirements allow.

Comment: It makes a lot more sense for `width` and `height` to be the same type.

Comment: @JamesRoot: Well, it's a square, so by definition they're also the same value.

Answer (score 1):

It is doable, you need however two different types for the width and height, if I understand the question correctly (and note that this is a rectangle, not a square, technically speaking).

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename W, typename H>
class Rect {
    W width;
    H height;
public:
    Rect(const W w, const H h): width(w), height(h) {}
    Rect(): width(0), height(0) {}
    W get_width() { return width; }
    H get_height() { return height; }
};

template <typename W, typename H>
void show_rect(Rect<W, H> r)
{
    std::cout << r.get_width()
              << "x"
              << r.get_height()
              << "="
              << r.get_width() * r.get_height()
              << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    show_rect(Rect<int, int>{});
    show_rect(Rect<double, long>{0.3, 8});
}
```

You can see how you can overload the constructor to initialize with default values. You also see how you can write a function that takes an object of that class as an argument.

With this, I get:

```
$ make rect
g++ -std=c++14 -pedantic -Wall -O2    rect.cpp   -o rect
$ ./rect
0x0=0
0.3x8=2.4
```

But I am really not sure about the wisdom of doing it like this. I am sure someone will explain in the comments :)

Comment: So you would have to make the whole class a template. Would it be possible to just template within the class instead of the whole class ?

Comment: You could add a function `template<typename W, typename H> Rect<W,H> make_rect(W w, H h) { return Rect<W,H>(w, h); }` so that the user can create `Rect` objects without having to specify template parameters

Comment: @M.M Yes. I leave this as an exercise to the user :)

Comment: @BumptheTrump I am not sure how you are envisioning this. You want to create an object, but you don't want to tell the compiler what it looks like?

Comment: If I use the method by @M.M , how would I declare the private width and height variables ?

Comment: @BumptheTrump my method is additional to Boris's code which shows you how the class must be

Comment: @BumptheTrump Yes, you can add the definition from the comment of M.M verbatim to the code already shown I think. It is a convenience function, if you will. You might need to hit the books a bit if you want to learn C++ though, this will not get you too far.

Comment: @Boris + M.M , combining both your approaches helped me achieve what I wanted in the end. I was looking at a kind of pythonic way of making a class take in multiple types of the same variable

Comment: @BumptheTrump Glad to help (and please accept the answer if it helped you). Keep in mind that in Python (or other "dynamic" languages), your objects are just collections that can change as the program is running. You can do this in C++ too, of course, but it is a trade-off that you need to evaluate. It really comes down to the overall architecture of your program. A rule of thumb (no matter what language you are programming in) is to go with the code that is least surprising to someone else experienced in that language.